# Neural Networks Extending Learning Domain

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a simple function **f** : **R**->**R**, f(x) = x<sup>2</sup> + a, and would like to create a neural network to learn that function, as entirely as it can. Currently, I have a pytorch implementation that takes in inputs of a limited range of course, from x0 to xN with a particular number of points. Each epoch, the training data is randomly perturbed, in efforts to not only learn the relationship on the same grid points each time.

Currently, it does a great job of learning on the function on the range it is trained on, but is it at all feasible to train in such a way that can extend this learning beyond what it is trained on? Currently the behavior outside the training range seems dependent on the activation function. For example, with ReLU, the true function (orange) compared to the networks prediction (blue) are below:
[image]

I understand that if I transform the input vector to higher dimensions that contain higher powers of x, it may work out pretty well, but for a generalized case and how I plan to implement this in the future it won't work as well on non-polynomial functions.

One thought that came to mind is from support vector machines and the choice of a kernel, and how the radial basis kernel gets around this generalization issue, but I'm not sure if this can be applied here without the inner product properties of svm.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called extrapolation (as opposed to interpolation which is predicting a value that is inside the trained domain / range). There is never a good solution for extrapolation and using higher powers can give you a better fit for a specific problem, but if you change the fitted curve slightly (either change its x and y-intercept, one of the powers, etc) the extrapolation will be pretty bad again.

This is also why neural networks use a large data set (to maximize their input range and rely on interpolation) and why over-training / over fitting (which is what you're trying to do) is a bad idea; it never works well in the general case.

Comment: I see, that does make sense. Guess I'll need to define a domain for any testing and train based on that, Thank you!